# Azure AD B2C - Test user for automated testing

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure AD B2C Login and Registration user flow in my mobile app. These pages has MFA for the normal users. My question is, Can I create a test user which can skip the MFA(OTP via SMS) process without using Custom Policy.